# How to push remote1:master to remote2:branch123 safely

Tags: git, github, branch, git-remote

**Problem**: I want to push branch from one remote to another remote. Here is what I have done so far:

**note**: I have one remote already let say `origin1`

1. `git remote add origin2 repolink.git`
2. `git fetch origin2`

now I have local `origin2` and its branches.

Structure:

```
local
 master
remote
 origin1
  master
 origin2
  master
  branch123
```

**Require**: I want to push `local:master` to `orgin2:branch123`. `branch123` already have source files and commits.

**option:1** `origin2:branch123` last commit can be parent of `local:master` init commit. I guess that might be **rebasing**.
**option:2** `origin2:branch123` is forcefully replaced by `local:master`. In which case I will lose commits of origin2:branch123 which was branched by `origin2:master`. I don't know whether in this case `local:master` will conflict with `origin2:master` in doing so (option:2)

which option is safe. I prefer `rebasing` because `origin2:branch123` last commit is almost identical to `remote1:master` `init commit`.
Please see image:
[image]

Please advise which option is safe or best and what commands are useful. I am a bit naive right now in version control management.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

`git push origin2 master:newbranch` // master is origin1:master
`git fetch origin2`
`git checkout newbranch` // from origin2 i.e. copy of origin1:master
`git checkout branch123` //make sure you don't have any staged or untracked files in branch123
// `HEAD` is on branch123
`git rebase --onto newbranch`
`git push` // this will push `branch123` which is now have commits of `newbranch` as well but git will prompt to `merge` or `rebase`, I did `rebase` and `origin2:branch123` `HEAD` moved to `local:branch123` `HEAD` which was rebased onto `origin2:newbranch`. (one can search rebasing a remote branch etc. I did it in pycharm IDE so it prompted me two option `merge` or `rebase`.

Anyways. A bit of luck now I have one `unrelated branch history` `origin1:master` added to another branch `origin2:branch123` which I can merge in `origin2:main/master` branch.